# как сделать что главная сцена запускалось через 3 секунды?

Tags: c#, unity3d

я заметил что когда при запуске игры,именно во время заставки unity  касаешься пальцем эти тачи обрабатываются.ну и вот решил исправить это именно так: запуск сцены через три секунды.

Comment: вот пример [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QfO11O4pUp8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вероятнее всего тебя интересует реализация экрана загрузки.
Для этого нужно что бы стартовая сцена была пустой.

Когда она загрузится полностью ты делаешь асинхронную загрузку необходимого тебе левела. Когда эта сцена полностью подгрузится, то тогда уже переключаешся на нее.

Детали реализации можешь посмотреть в документации:
[SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html)

Comment: и скрипт который у меня получилось я сохраняю в первую сцену(LoadScene) или во второю ?

Comment: первая сцена - промежуточная. .LoadSceneAsync вызывается из нее.

Comment: спасибо.\\помогает

Comment: всего хорошего вам.)

Comment: нужно отметить галочкой что ответ решил проблему. Она под цифрами слева от ответа. Удачи в программировании :)